# FluentUI Web Components Select with Blazor - Select Enum values

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, fluent-ui, fast-blazor

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/components/select?pivots=blazor

https://github.com/microsoft/fast-blazor/blob/main/examples/FluentUI.Demo.Shared/Pages/SelectPage.razor

https://brave-cliff-0c0c93310.azurestaticapps.net/SelectPage

Examples only shows values with `string` and `int`. What can I do to select `enum` values without writing custom converters?

```
<h2>Default</h2>
<FluentSelect @bind-Value="@selectValue">
    <FluentOption>This option has no value</FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Disabled="true">This option is disabled</FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Value="@("hi")">This option has a value</FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Selected="true">This option is selected by default</FluentOption>
</FluentSelect>

<h2>Default with an int type</h2>
<FluentSelect @bind-Value="@selectValue2">
    <FluentOption Value=1>1</FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Value=-1 Disabled="true">-1</FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Value=2>2</FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Value=3 Selected="true">3</FluentOption>
</FluentSelect>

@code {
    string? selectValue;
    int selectValue2;

    List<Option<string>> stringOptions = new()
        {
            { new Option<string> { Key = "1", Value = "One" } },
            { new Option<string> { Key = "2", Value = "Two", Selected = true } },
            { new Option<string> { Key = "3", Value = "Three" } }

        };

    List<Option<int>> intOptions = new()
        {
            { new Option<int> { Key = 1, Value = 1, Disabled = true } },
            { new Option<int> { Key = 2, Value = 2 } },
            { new Option<int> { Key = 3, Value = 3 } }

        };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
<FluentSelect @bind-Value="@threatDto.Severity" Options="@SeverityOptionList" Required="true">
</FluentSelect>

@code {

    List<Option<Severity?>> SeverityOptionList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Severity)).Cast<Severity?>().Where(x => x != Severity.None).Select(x => new Option<Severity?> { Key = x.Value, Value = x.Value }).ToList();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class ThreatDto
{

    [Required, EnumDataType(typeof(Severity))]
    public Severity? Severity { get; set; }
        
}

public enum Severity
{
    None = 0,
    Critical = 1,
    High = 2,
    Medium = 3,
    Low = 4
}
```

Comment: I can't get your code to work as FluentSelect doesn't have an Options attribute. It uses Items instead. https://brave-cliff-0c0c93310.azurestaticapps.net/Select . Am i doing something wrong?